# Insert a string to a path

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/13007805372971.jpg
```

What should I do to append a string before file name ? I would like to look like this

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/sometext_13007805372971.jpg
```

Comment: Is the prefix "folder1/folder2/folder3" always the same?

Comment: The best solution would be a `pathinfo()` based approach that actually cuts out the file name according to the current OS's rules, not one that uses the slashes `/`

Comment: Have you found the solution? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function, which is designed to parse paths.

```
$s='folder1/folder2/folder3/13007805372971.jpg';
$x='sometext_';
$fos=pathinfo($s);

$s2=$fos['dirname'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$x.$fos['basename'];
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [SplFileInfo class](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

```
$file = new SplFileInfo('folder1/folder2/folder3/13007805372971.jpg');
printf('%s/sometext_%s', $file->getPath(), $file->getBasename());
```

Can also use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of hardcoding the slash into the call.

[Live Demo](http://codepad.org/bih8h4U7)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using the following code.

```
$string           = 'folder1/folder2/folder3/13007805372971.jpg';
$last_slash_pos   = strrpos($string, '/');
$path             = substr($string, 0, $last_slash_pos + 1);
$filename         = substr($string, $last_slash_pos + 1);

$filename_prefix  = 'sometext_';
$new_filename     = $path . $filename_prefix . $filename;

echo $new_filename; // Output: folder1/folder2/folder3/sometext_13007805372971.jpg
```

[View Live Version](http://codepad.org/KqASPxnc)

Answer (score 3):

```
$filePath = 'folder1/folder2/folder3/13007805372971.jpg';
$str = 'sometext_';

$newPath = dirname($filePath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $str . basename($filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace("/\/([^\/]+)$/", "/sometext_\\1", "folder1/folder2/folder3/13007805372971.jpg");`

This takes the part after the last slash, and adds sometext_ right after it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the components of the filename using pathinfo and then plug in your addition as required.

```
$path_parts =pathinfo($string);
$string = $path_parts['dirname'].'/sometext_'.$path_parts['basename'];
```